# How can I do integration tests in NiFi without having an instance up?

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to do integration tests with NiFi flows that have custom processors, but it seems that every way that is up to date uses the the NiFi API, which requires me to have an instance up. While it is doable, I would not prefer to have it that way.

The only other option I have seen is called `plumber`, but it hasn't been updated in years and doesn't seem to have the ability for custom processors.

If anyone has any idea for NiFi flow/integration testing, let me know.

Comment: Integration tests supposed to have flow running. So, you need a nifi instance.. However it's possible to run a unit test of one particular processor without nifi instance.

Comment: I don't see any limits to include dependency to custom  processors for https://github.com/TouK/plumber  - sounds like it's a simple wrapper to nifi-mock library to emulate flow.